# Plotting multiple parametric 3D curves without using the Show command

Tags: plotting, function-construction, parametric-functions, visualization

How can I plot multiple parametric 3D curves on a single graph without the need to combine them using `Show`? Additionally, is there a way to clearly distinguish which curves correspond to which `{x0, y0, z0}` values and visualize the intersections of each curve with the `x`, `y`, and the `z` axes?

```
ClearAll[x0, y0, z0, t]
num = 10;
x0Values = Subdivide[0, 2, num];
y0Values = Subdivide[0, 3, num];
z0Values = Subdivide[0, 8, num];
combinedList = Transpose[{x0Values, y0Values, z0Values}];
x[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := 
  x0 Cos[100000 t] + (2 + y0) Sin[100000 t];
y[t_, {x0_, y0_, 
    z0_}] := (2 + y0 - 2 Cos[100000 t]) Cos[100000 t] - 
   Sin[100000 t] (x0 + 2 Sin[100000 t]);
z[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := -100000 t + z0;
plots = ParametricPlot3D[{x[t, #], y[t, #], z[t, #]}, {t, 0, 
      30*10^-6}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], ImageSize -> 250] & /@ 
   combinedList;
Show[plots]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To get different colors automatically for a plot, the idea is to do this

```
 data=.... (*generate list of data*)
 Plot[Evaluate[data],.....]
```

What you did is generate one plot for each data item, and then used `Show` to combine them. This is why Mathematica was not able to make different color for each curve. To obtain automatically different color, you need to pass the list to Plot command in the call itself (with Evaluate in there)

So using this approach, your code now becomes

```
ClearAll[x0, y0, z0, t]
num = 10;
x0Values = Subdivide[0, 2, num];
y0Values = Subdivide[0, 3, num];
z0Values = Subdivide[0, 8, num];
combinedList = Transpose[{x0Values, y0Values, z0Values}];
x[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := x0 Cos[100000 t] + (2 + y0) Sin[100000 t];
y[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := (2 + y0 - 2 Cos[100000 t]) Cos[100000 t] - 
   Sin[100000 t] (x0 + 2 Sin[100000 t]);
z[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := -100000 t + z0;
data = {x[t, #], y[t, #], z[t, #]} & /@ combinedList;
```

Now we have the data, then do

```
plots = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@data, {t, 0, 30*10^-6}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
  ImageSize -> 450, PlotLegends -> {combinedList}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> and visualize the intersections of each curve with the x, y, and z
> axes?

Sorry, I do not understand this one. May be someone else could help with this part.

Comment: I'm sorry that I made a mistake. The time should be `30*10^-6` instead. I want to plot in the given range.

Comment: @emnha Ok, now it matches your plot. I knew something must have been changed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to visualize the range of the x, y, and z functions with the provided x0, y0, and z0 values from the combinedList. When I view the plot, I want to know the ranges of x, y, and z.

Comment: @emnha I do not really know how do this as I do not understand it. But you can wait and I am sure someone will know and help with this last part.

Answer (score 5):

- The code can be simplified by using `Subdivide[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 8}, num]`.
- Since the curve through `{x0,y0,z0}` when `t==0`, we use `Mesh` to draw such initial points.
- I also do not know the other requests.

```
Clear[combinedList];
num = 10;
combinedList = Subdivide[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 8}, num];
x[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := x0 Cos[100000 t] + (2 + y0) Sin[100000 t];
y[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := (2 + y0 - 2 Cos[100000 t]) Cos[100000 t] - 
   Sin[100000 t] (x0 + 2 Sin[100000 t]);
z[t_, {x0_, y0_, z0_}] := -100000 t + z0;
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t, #], y[t, #], z[t, #]} & /@ combinedList // 
   Evaluate, {t, 0, 30*10^-6}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
  ImageSize -> 250, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1/100*30*10^-6}}, MeshStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[10]}, 
  Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> {Arrowheads[{{.035, .85}}], Arrow[pts]}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't mention this in my original post. Do you know of any method to add arrows to each curve to show that time increases in that direction?

Comment: @emnha  Add `/. 
 Line[pts_] :> {Arrowheads[{{.035, .85}}], Arrow[pts]}`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the "combined combinedList" from cvgmt:

```
num = 10;
combinedList = Subdivide[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 8}, num];

x = #1 Cos[100000 t] + (2 + #2) Sin[100000 t] & @@@ combinedList;
y = (2 + #2 - 2 Cos[100000 t]) Cos[100000 t] - Sin[100000 t] (#1 + 2 Sin[100000 t]) & @@@ combinedList;
z = -100000 t + #3 & @@@ combinedList;

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ Transpose[{x, y, z}], {t, 0, 30*10^-6},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
 ImageSize -> 450,
 PlotLegends -> {combinedList}]
```

[image]